# Angularjs promises. Controller + service doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just want to use load bar in my app. I got service in angularjs like this

```
app.service('gethostsbyip', [ '$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  this.gethostsbyip = function(hostname, username, password){
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var result = $http.post(REST_API_IP + 'discover?ip=' + hostname + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password).then(function(resp){
            deffered.resolve(result);
            location.href="#createvirtualization";
            toastr.success('Your hosts, templates, networks have been updated!', 'Data was loaded!');
        }).catch(function(e){
            toastr.error('Some data in your form is incorrect. Please, try again!', 'Error!');
        });
    return deffered.promise;
  };
}]);
```

And in the angular controller, I need to change flag into `false` value after my service (`gethostsbyip.gethostsbyip`) is done.

When the function runs without errors the flag changes, but I need to change the flag in case of an error in the service.

```
app.controller('discoverCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.submitButt = function(hostname, username, password){
    if(!hostname || !username || !password){
    }
    else {
      $scope.flag = true;
      gethostsbyip.gethostsbyip(hostname, username, password).then(function(res){
        $scope.test = false;
      })
      .catch(function(e){
        $scope.test = false;
      })
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It seem you missing inject `gethostsbyip` service to your controller?

Comment: no, it's okey, i just forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

`then` event accepts `two` parameter.

```
app.controller('discoverCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {

$scope.submitButt = function(hostname, username, password){
    if(!hostname || !username || !password){
    }
    else {
        $scope.flag = true;
        gethostsbyip.gethostsbyip(hostname, username, password)
        .then(
        // you currently have one callback in your `then` method
        function(res){
            $scope.test = false;
        }
        // solution
        , function(resForErrorCase){
            $scope.test = false;
        })
    .catch(function(e){
        $scope.test = false;
    })
  }
};
```

[Promise definition reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work. I think, because my service return err, and when i called it in the controller it doesn't use then method...

Comment: in your method definition, are you rejecting the response on error. `deffered.reject()`. I see only `deffered.resolve()`. Which is why your controller isn't able to finish on error.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it.

Comment: you don't need to inject $q anymore

Answer (score 0):

Reject the promise if error occurs

```
.catch(function(e) {
  deffered.reject(e);
  toastr.error('Some data in your form is incorrect. Please, try again!', 'Error!');
});
```